# Can't run .net Framework Nunit project, from terminal nor pipelines

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, azure-pipelines, .net-4.8

I have an NUnit project that has a lot of .NET Framework class libraries dependencies, so the project itself is a .NET Framework.

If I run my tests from Visual Studio, the project runs fine and the tests are run correctly.

However if I try to do the same from Terminal, doing `dotnet build` I get a lot of errors, like if the cli couldnt restore packages, and therefore I can't build the project nor run the tests from the terminal.

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestFixtureAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestFixture' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The same is happening to me when doing this on Azure Pipelines.

Any ideas? Is there a problem between the dotnet cli and the project being a .NET Framework one?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you add the required packages?

Comment: I have them added on the csproj as package references like: 

`<PackageReference Include="NUnit">
      <Version>3.13.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>`
`<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter">
      <Version>4.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
` 
@Bharat